# I want to use bxslider in nuxt.js. (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, bxslider, nuxt.js

Developed as nuxt.js.
I want to implement a slider. I want to use bxslider.

From nuxt.config.js

```
head: {

  script: [
    {type: 'text / javascript', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'},
    {type: 'text / javascript', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js'},
  ],

  link: [
    {rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text / css', href: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.css'},
  ],

}
```

I have called bxslider.

In the vue component,

```
mounted () {
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider()
}
```

The following error occurs.

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $ (...). BxSlider is not a function"
>
> TypeError: $ (...). BxSlider is not a function

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at documentation https://nuxtjs.org/examples/plugins

in `nuxt.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    vendor: ['bxslider']
  },
 plugins: [
   // ssr: false to only include it on client-side
   { src: '~/plugins/bxslider.js', ssr: false }
 ]
}
```

and in plugins folder create `bxslider.js` file and do the following

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import bxslider from 'bxslider'
Vue.use(bxslider)
```

Comment: The error message has changed. **TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery___default(...)(...).bxSlider is not a function**

Comment: I installed bxslider with npm and implemented it as a plugin!
I admire your knowledge. You are very good.

Comment: @hyeokluv I did the same thing but still getting "BxSlider is not a function" Can you help me?